# How to make it so all schema brackets are horizontally aligned?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, schemata

I'm currently trying to put together a visual diagram using schemata which currently looks like this:

[image]

How would I make it so all of the curly brackets are aligned horizontally? Currently this is what it looks like in LaTex:

```
\schema
 {\schemabox{0}}
 {
 \schemabox{\textit{A staff member may authorize the transfer of an inmate
 into a structured } \\
 \textit{intervention unit under subsection 29.01(1) only if the staff member is satisfied } \\
 \textit{that there is no reasonable
 alternative to the inmate’s confinement in a structured} \\
 \textit{intervention unit and
 the staff member believes on reasonable grounds that...}}
 }\smallskip

\vspace{5mm}

\subsection*{s.29.01(2)}\\

\schema
{\schemabox{5-7 days}}
{
\schemabox{\textit{The institutional head shall determine, in accordance with 
regulations made} \\
\textit{under paragraph 96(g), whether an inmate should remain in a structured intervention} \\
\textit{unit within the period of five working days that begins on the first working day }\\
\textit{on which the inmate is confined in the unit.}}
}

\vspace{5mm}

\subsection*{37.3(1)(b)}

\schema
{\schemabox{35-37 days}}
{
\schemabox{\textit{The institutional head shall determine, in accordance with regulations}\\ 
\textit{made under paragraph 96(g), whether an inmate should remain in a structured} \\
i\textit{ntervention unit...
within the period that begins on the day on which the}\\
\textit{determination under subsection 29.01(2) is made and that ends on the expiry} \\
\textit{of the period of 30 days that begins on the first day on which the inmate is confined}\\
\textit{in the unit;}}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! please make your given code snippet be compilable then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: So you have a series of these you want aligned? That is, they're not part of a single diagram as you've coded them?

Comment: @cfr yes that is correct

Comment: Please make your code compilable.